# MS SQL Server Update/Insert Correctly with variables Java project

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

Hi i have a problem with my sql statement in case where im updating variables into tables. How should i wrote it properly ? 1,2,3 works just fine, problem is on case 4. It need to be a variable that i get from a user so he can modify the table. After i enter variables i get "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException" and eclipse poitning    st.executeUpdate();

```
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static int menu(){
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("     1. Wyswietl tabele");
        System.out.println("     2. Dodaj rekord");
        System.out.println("     3. Usun rekord");
        System.out.println("     4. Modyfikuj rekord");
        System.out.println("     0. Koniec");

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int w = in.nextInt();

        return w;
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Connection connection = connect();

        Statement st = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        new Scanner(System.in);

        int wybor = menu();

        while(wybor!=0){
            switch(wybor){
                case 1:
                            System.out.println("Podaj nazwe tabeli (osoba, miasto, kraj, zawód):");
                            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                            String nazwa = input.nextLine();

                        if(nazwa.equals("osoba"))
                        {
                         st = connection.createStatement();
                         rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT osoba_id, osoba_imie, osoba_nazwisko, miasto_id, kraj_id, zawód_id FROM osoba");

                         System.out.println(String.format("%s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s","id", "imie", "nazwisko", "miasto", "kraj", "zawód"));
                         System.out.println();
                         while (rs.next()) {

                             System.out.println(String.format("%s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s",rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getString(5), rs.getString(6)));

                         }
                        rs.close();
                        st.close();
                        }
                        else if(nazwa.equals("miasto"))
                        {
                        st = connection.createStatement();
                         rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT miasto_id, miasto_nazwa, miasto_kod FROM miasto");

                         System.out.println(String.format("%s, %s, %s", "id", "nazwa", "kod"));
                         System.out.println();
                         while (rs.next()) {                

                             System.out.println(String.format("%s, %s, %s",rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3)));

                         }
                        rs.close();
                        st.close();
                        }
                        else if(nazwa.equals("kraj"))
                        {
                             st = connection.createStatement();
                             rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT kraj_id, kraj_nazwa, kraj_kod FROM kraj");

                             System.out.println(String.format("%s, %s, %s", "kraj", "nazwa", "kod"));
                             System.out.println();
                             while (rs.next()) {

                                 System.out.println(String.format("%s, %s, %s",rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3)));

                             }  

                         rs.close();
                         st.close();
                        }   
                        else if(nazwa.equals("zawód"))
                        {
                             st = connection.createStatement();
                             rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT zawód_id, zawód_rodzaj, zawód_stanowisko, zawód_pensja FROM zawód");

                             System.out.println(String.format("%s, %s, %s, %s", "zawód", "rodzaj", "stanowisko", "pensja"));
                             System.out.println();
                             while (rs.next()) {

                                 System.out.println(String.format("%s, %s, %s, %s",rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4)));

                             }  

                         rs.close();
                         st.close();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        System.out.println("Podales zla nazwe tabeli");
                        } 


                        break;

                case 2:

                        System.out.println("Podaj nazwe tabeli (osoba, miasto, kraj, zawód):");
                        Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
                        nazwa = input1.nextLine();
                        st = connection.createStatement();

                        if(nazwa.equals("osoba"))
                        {
                            System.out.println("Podaj id:");
                            Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                            String id = input2.nextLine();
                            System.out.println("Podaj imie:");
                            input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                            String imie = input2.nextLine();
                            System.out.println("Podaj nazwisko:");
                            input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                            String nazwisko = input2.nextLine();
                            System.out.println("Podaj miasto_id:");
                            input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                            String miasto = input2.nextLine();
                            System.out.println("Podaj kraj_id:");
                            input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                            String kraj = input2.nextLine();
                            System.out.println("Podaj zawód_id:");
                            input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                            String zawód = input2.nextLine();


                         st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO osoba(osoba_id, osoba_imie, osoba_nazwisko, miasto, kraj, zawód) VALUES('"+id+"','"+imie+"', '"+nazwisko+"', '"+miasto+"', '"+kraj+"', '"+zawód+"')");
                        // st.close();      
                        }
                        else if(nazwa.equals("miasto"))
                        {
                            System.out.println("Podaj nazwę:");
                            Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                            String nazwa1 = input2.nextLine();
                            System.out.println("Podaj kod:");
                            input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                            String kod = input2.nextLine();                         

                         st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO miasto(miasto_nazwa, kod) VALUES('"+nazwa1+"', '"+kod+"')");
                        // st.close();
                        } 
                        else if(nazwa.equals("kraj"))
                        {
                            System.out.println("Podaj id kraju:");
                            Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                            String kraj_id = input2.nextLine();
                            System.out.println("Podaj nazwę:");
                            input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                            String nazwa2 = input2.nextLine();
                            System.out.println("Podaj kod:");
                            input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                            String kod = input2.nextLine();


                          st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO kraj (kraj_id, nazwa, kod) VALUES("+kraj_id+", "+nazwa2+", '"+kod+"')");

                            // st.close();  
                        }
                        else if(nazwa.equals("zawód"))
                        {
                            System.out.println("Podaj rodzaj:");
                            Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                            String rodzaj = input2.nextLine();
                            System.out.println("Podaj stanowisko:");
                            input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                            String stanowisko = input2.nextLine();  
                            System.out.println("Podaj pensję:");
                            input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                            String pensja = input2.nextLine();

                         st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO zawód(rodzaj, stanowisko, pensja) VALUES("+rodzaj+","+stanowisko+","+pensja+"");
                        /// st.close();
                        }
                        else
                        System.out.println("Podales zla nazwe tabeli");                     
                        st.close();
                        break;

                case 3:

                    System.out.println("Podaj nazwe tabeli (osoba, miasto, kraj, zawód):");
                     input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    nazwa = input1.nextLine();


                        st = connection.createStatement();
                        if(nazwa.equals("osoba"))
                        {
                            System.out.println("Podaj id usuwanego wiersza:");
                            input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
                            String id = input1.nextLine();  
                        st.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM "+nazwa+" WHERE osoba_id="+id+"");
                        }
                        else if(nazwa.equals("miasto"))
                        {                  
                            System.out.println("Podaj id usuwanego wiersza:");
                            input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
                            String id = input1.nextLine();  
                        st.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM "+nazwa+" WHERE miasto_id="+id+"");
                        }
                        else if(nazwa.equals("kraj"))
                        {
                            System.out.println("Podaj id usuwanego wiersza:");
                            input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
                            String id = input1.nextLine();  
                           st.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM "+nazwa+" WHERE kraj_id="+id+""); 
                        }
                        else if(nazwa.equals("zawód"))
                        {
                            System.out.println("Podaj id usuwanego wiersza:");
                            input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
                            String id = input1.nextLine();  
                           st.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM "+nazwa+" WHERE zawód_id="+id+""); 
                        }
                        else
                        System.out.println("Podales zla nazwe tabeli"); 
                        st.close();  
                    break;

                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Podaj nazwe tabeli (osoba, miasto, kraj, zawód):");
                 input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
                nazwa = input1.nextLine();

                if(nazwa.equals("osoba"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Podaj id modyfikowanego wiersza:");
                    Scanner input3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String id = input3.nextLine();  
                    System.out.println("Podaj nowe imię:");
                    input3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String imie = input3.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Podaj nowe nazwisko:");
                    input3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String nazwisko = input3.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Podaj id miasta:");
                    input3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String miasto_id = input3.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Podaj id kraju:");
                    input3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String kraj_id = input3.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Podaj id zawodu:");
                    input3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String zawód_id = input3.nextLine();
                st.executeUpdate("UPDATE osoba SET osoba_imie="+imie+", osoba_nazwisko="+nazwisko+", miasto_id ="+miasto_id+", kraj_id="+kraj_id+", zawód_id="+zawód_id+"  WHERE osoba_id="+id+"");
                }
                else if(nazwa.equals("miasto"))
                {                  
                    System.out.println("Podaj id modyfikowanego wiersza:");
                    Scanner input3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String id = input3.nextLine();  
                    System.out.println("Podaj nową nazwę:");
                    input3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String nazwa3 = input3.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Podaj nowy kod:");
                    input3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String kod = input3.nextLine();

                st.executeUpdate("UPDATE miasto SET miasto_nazwa="+nazwa3+", miasto_kod="+kod+" WHERE miasto_id="+id+"");
                }
                else if(nazwa.equals("kraj"))
                {                  
                    System.out.println("Podaj id modyfikowanego wiersza:");
                    Scanner input3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String id = input3.nextLine();  
                    System.out.println("Podaj nową nazwę:");
                    input3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String nazwa4 = input3.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Podaj nowy kod:");
                    input3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String kod2 = input3.nextLine();

                st.executeUpdate("UPDATE kraj SET kraj_nazwa="+nazwa4+", kraj_kod="+kod2+" WHERE kraj_id="+id+"");
                }
                else if(nazwa.equals("zawód"))
                {                  
                    System.out.println("Podaj id modyfikowanego wiersza:");
                    Scanner input3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String id = input3.nextLine();  
                    System.out.println("Podaj nowy rodzaj:");
                    input3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String rodzaj = input3.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Podaj nowe stanowisko:");
                    input3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String stanowisko = input3.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Podaj nową pensję:");
                    input3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String pensja = input3.nextLine();

                st.executeUpdate("UPDATE zawód SET zawód_rodzaj="+rodzaj+", zawód_stanowisko="+stanowisko+", zawód_pensja="+pensja+" WHERE zawód_id="+id+"");
                }

                else
                System.out.println("Podales zla nazwe tabeli");
                st.close();  

                    break;
            }

            System.out.println("\nWciśnij Enter, aby kontynuować...");
            System.in.read();

            wybor = menu();
        }

        System.out.println("     ******************");
        System.out.println("\n     Koniec\n\n");
    }

    private static Connection connect() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getConnect();
    }

}
```

Comment: This code is Purely encapsulated and has no UML design in it, sort of dumping the code all in one page. I would suggest for you to seperate your concerns between workflow and data, also it would be good practice if you look at JPA or Hibernate in java to be used as your ORM... as for the insert can you tell on which line?

Comment: well as for INSERT i figure this out and its now working But still Update return this annoying java.lang.NullPointerException and pointing my  st.executeUpdate();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the

```
                    st = connection.createStatement();
```

in case 4.

However you can really optimize and shorten your code by reusing variables, initializing stuff only once and not on every case, etc.

It would help you avoid such errors, and make them easier to find.